# Is it possible to add a note to an Illustrator project similar to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Does anyone know if it is possible to add a note to an Illustrator project, the way you can with the note tool in Photoshop? Currently, I've created a new layer, and set it to not print, but not super efficient.

Answer (score 4):

Not really. Your current method is as good as any other.

There is no "note" tool or feature within Illustrator.

But you can add some notes via the **Attributes Panel**. These are pretty hidden in terms of someone else finding them, but you can access object attribute notes via actions and/or scripting.

Answer (score 3):

What I do?
I create an Artboard, name it Notes, create a Layer, name it whatever you think will get someone's attention and put the notations on that board.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot to your answer?

Comment: @got2d-xine Yes. The name of a layer in Illustrator can contains many letters. But, this is single line and I think describing a layer in the name of layer is not standard; But can be use.